# Variable losing value in delegation pattern

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I'm trying to learn about delegation in Objective-C, and am having a minor issue with a variable losing it's data in the transfer process. I have Class1 that contains an `NSMutableArray`. The array gets populated, then I would like to transfer the array's values to Class2, and display it. Here is the relevant code in Class1:

```
 //Class1.h
 @class Class1;
 // define the protocol for the delegate
 @protocol Class1Delegate

 @required
 -(void)sayHello:(Class1 *)customClass withAntArray:(NSMutableArray *)antArray;

 @end

 @interface Class1 : MySuperClassName

 @property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

 -(void)helloDelegate;

 @end


    //Class1.m:
@interface Class1 ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *antOccurenceTimes;
@end
@implementation Class1
@synthesize antOccurenceTimes;

-(void)helloDelegate
{
    // send the message to the delegate


 [_delegate sayHello:self withAntArray:self.antOccurenceTimes];
}
```

Now, this is what I have in Class2:

```
#import "Class1.h"
@interface Class2 : UIView <Class1Delegate>
@end
// Class2.m:
- (void)appropriateTimeToCallMethod {
    Class1 *initAntMarks = [[Class1 alloc] init];
    initAntMarks.delegate = self;
    [initAntMarks helloDelegate];
}
-(void)sayHello:(Class1 *)customClass withAntArray:(NSMutableArray *)antArray {

    NSLog(@"Hello! %@", antArray.description);
}
```

The `antArray.description` reads as "NULL". Now, I figured that obviously it will be null, because I just created an entirely new instance of the class right before calling upon the needed method. I feel like I may have something mixed up, and being so new to delegation, I'm not sure exactly what. Does anyone know what I need to tweak to utilize Delegation?
I forgot to add that I did initialize it in Class1, and it gets populated just fine. It's only in class2 that this is occurring.

I initalize antOccuranceTimes in a separate method in ClassA in the snippet below, and the NSLog fires twice...

```
NSLog(@"Array initalized in class A"); 
antOccurenceTimes = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

to:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <Class1Delegate> delegate;
```

`assign` should only be used for C primitives, not Objective-c object references. You should also be checking if your object actually conforms to the delegate before messaging the delegate.

**Edit:**

I think you may be confused about the purpose of delegation.

```
Class1 *initAntMarks = [[Class1 alloc] init];
initAntMarks.delegate = self;
[initAntMarks helloDelegate];
```

Why are you calling a method on an object which in turn calls a delegate method when you could simply create a method that returns the `NSMutableArray`? The way you have your code currently set up requires that before the call to `-helloDelegate` you have to have filled the array with the appropriate objects. The purpose of delegation in MVC is to inform an object about an event that took place inside of another object. You are "delegating" the task off to another object, or you could say, that another object if responsible for the fulfillment of the task. Read the [Apple Docs on Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). Delegation in your code is not the correct pattern to implement, as I stated you can simply return that array with a method call.

**Edit 2:**

There are two ways you can achieve this, through property methods or through an explicit method that returns your array. If you choose to use property methods, the property declaration must be in the public interface i.e. the `.h` file so that your class can all the accessors when the object is being implemented.

```
//Inside the .h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *antOccurenceTimes;
```

This will automatically provide you with two accessor methods for the `antOccurenceTimes` property. These are the getter `-antOccurenceTimes` and setter `-setAntOccurenceTimes:` methods. Now after you initialize the class and fill your array you can call `-antOccurenceTimes` to return the array.

You can also create an explicit method that return the array:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)hello{

    //Do something here
    return _antOccurenceTimes;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are properly initializing `antOccurenceTimes` ? Post your `init` method.

Comment: It is initialized in ClassA like so
    `NSLog(@"Array initalized in class A");`
    `adOccurenceTimes = [NSMutableArray new];`
And the NSLog fires twice.

Comment: What do you mean by "Simply create a method that returns the NSMutableArray"? I understand that the code jumps around a little bit, I'm very new to this.

Comment: @John Sure I'll explain it. Don't worry, delegation really confused me before I became familiar with it.

Comment: @John See the Edit. If you are still confused let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have not yet initialized the `antOccurenceTimes`. Of cause it is nil. There are many options depending on what you need. You can, for example, initialize it in a `init` function:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if( self ) {
        antOccurenceTimes = [NSMutableArray array];
        [antOccurenceTimes addObject:@"Hello World"];
    }
}
```

Or maybe initialize it before you call the delegate the function.

```
-(void)helloDelegate
{
    // send the message to the delegate

    self.antOccurenceTimes = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    [self.antOccurenceTimes addObject:@"Hello World"];
    [_delegate sayHello:self withAntArray:self.antOccurenceTimes];
}
```

I think you get my point.

Comment: I forgot to add that I did initialize it in Class1, and it gets populated just fine. It's only in class2 that this is occurring.